# Tablets with QGIS data collection in the field + image capture?

Tags: qgis, data-capture

**Situation:** 
– In a student project, we are building a cataster/registry of pollard trees.
– We have geolocations of many trees and now we want to collect data about these trees in the field.
– We want to use open source software and lowcost equipment: an efficient solution, basically.

**What we have:**
– We are using QGIS for analysis
– We have tablets running Windows 8.1 and QGIS 
– Optionally we have external Bluetooth GPS sensors (but the tablets have internal GPS sensors as well)

**What we are able to do:**
– Use a customizes QGIS with an entry form in the field, to gather attribute data (got that already)

**Questions, what we are lacking:**
– Is there a good way to capture images of trees with the tablet camera in the field AND link them to tree data? Maybe a plugin or script or something?
– Is there a way to get the tablet internal GPS sensor working with Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bit of self promotion but this is exactly what I built [Roam](http://roam-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) ([version](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k74vvqxq3yhblk2/IntraMapsRoam.zip?dl=0)) for.

Roam is built on QGIS with Python. It's a fully standalone Python application (apart from the making the maps for which you need QGIS installed).

**EDIT** Due to Windows 8 GPS and how it works you have to use a tool called centrafuse localizer into order to expose the GPS to a COM port. It's cheap and has worked for me.

[image]
[image]

If you have your own application, you can see how I have done the camera stuff here: https://github.com/DMS-Aus/Roam/tree/master/src/roam/editorwidgets  (It uses a third part lib vidcap.pyd with the Python [wrapper](https://github.com/DMS-Aus/Roam/blob/master/src/roam/editorwidgets/VideoCapture.py))

Comment: As you responded, I have looked into your tool already… I am still wrangling with 2 things:
1. Windows 8.1 Location API does not provide COM Port, I guess, we have to use an external GPS Logger
2. Is there a way to register new points using roam? Could be, that people in the field discover new trees…

Comment: For 1. see edit, and 2. of course that is the whole point of it. Follow this: http://roam-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/admin-guide/projectadmin/

Comment: @NathanW may I ask you about the tablet or ultrabook you are using and would reccomend?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [MapIt - GIS Data Collector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.osedok.gisdatacollector)

It is not dependent on any web or desktop applications; incoming and outgoing files for Mapit can cook and work in that geographic information system, which you prefer e.g. qGIS.
Mapit has built a Form Designer: You can set the necessary fields and values ​​directly on the tablet or smartphone. Mapit able to import, create, edit and export points, lines and polygons; you can use the online service raster maps (eg, Google Maps or Open Street Map) or off-line tail cache; manager available flexible layers. Documentation is a simple but comprehensive and well illustrated…

[image: MapIt - Main Functions Schema]